# LDA model on weighted data - R

Tags: r, lda, weighting

I would like to use linear discriminant analysis model (lda) on my weighted data. In my data set, I have one column with weights which are not integers (I cant just replicate rows). lda function from *MASS* package does not allow me to use vector of weights for observations. Do you know, how deal with it ? I have tried also with *mlr* package but learner *classif.lda* still uses lda implementation from MASS package, so I get error:

`Error in checkLearnerBeforeTrain(task, learner, weights) : 
  Weights vector passed to train, but learner 'classif.lda' does not support that!`

Do you know how to solve this problem ?